# Amend the app icon in action bar in Android push notifications (GCN)

Tags: php, android, push-notification, coronasdk

I would like to add an image to the remote notifications that get sent through to the app when sent via Google Cloud Notifications.

I'm sending the notification through to Google via PHP.  This in itself didn't seem to quite match the documentation I've found, which is telling me to send a 'message' parameter, when in actual fact it's 'alert' that shows on the app.

Below is my PHP code:

```
public function send_notification($registation_ids, $message) { 
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    echo 'Message: '.$message.'<br>';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registation_ids,
        'data' => array(
            'message' => $message,
            'alert' => $message
        )
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I would have thought that I just need to send an icon along with the payload, but I cannot find any documentation to support this.

The other option would be to have the icons on the app itself, and then call a variable in the payload to reference that icon, but cannot find any documentation to support that either.

As a side note, the app is built using Corona SDK, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transpires that Corona looks for a specific filename within the root of the project and uses that.  There are 3 files name formats, each with several versions for different DPI.  You cannot, at present and to my knowledge, change this icon dependant on the payload of the alert.

White, for Android 3.0+

```
IconNotificationDefault-ldpi-v11.png
IconNotificationDefault-mdpi-v11.png
IconNotificationDefault-hdpi-v11.png
IconNotificationDefault-xhdpi-v11.png
```

Grey, for Android 2.3-3.0

```
IconNotificationDefault-ldpi-v9.png
IconNotificationDefault-mdpi-v9.png
IconNotificationDefault-hdpi-v9.png
IconNotificationDefault-xhdpi-v9.png
```

Black, for everything else

```
IconNotificationDefault-ldpi.png
IconNotificationDefault-mdpi.png
IconNotificationDefault-hdpi.png
IconNotificationDefault-xhdpi.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send whatever data you want from the server, as long as you don't send more than 4K of data.
As for whether you should send `message` or `alert`, that entirely depends on the code in the client side, since that's the code that looks for these parameters and uses their values.

To send an icon directly with the payload, you'll have to encode the image to a string and include that string in the payload (assuming it's a small enough image). Your app will have to decode that string in order to display the icon. Your other option, to send a reference to the icon, makes more sense. Again, it's the client (application) code that has to handle that reference.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, but with this being a Corona app I don't seem to have that sort of control. That said, this isn't a unique problem, so there must be a way to change the icon used.  Currently it's the warning symbol (triangle with exclamation mark in the centre), which looks very wrong.

Comment: @mikemike Don't you have access to the code that displays the notification? I'm not familiar with Corona, so I'm not sure which part you are developing and which part you use as is.

Comment: It appears you can't change the icon ad-hoc, but you can change it from default.  There's a specific filename is looks for within the compiled project.  Thanks anyway though